# LoadLibraryEx: Parameters get lost in 64bit

Tags: c++, 64-bit, dllexport

I have a 64bit-DLL which exports the function

```
 __cdecl int (*function)(IN wchar_t* file, OUT VARIANT &htmlFile, IN wchar_t* path);
```

which is implemented as

```
int CShellWrapperx64Module:function(wchar_t* file, VARIANT &htmlFile, wchar_t* path) {
    VariantInit(&htmlFile);
    htmlFile.vt = VT_BSTR;
    htmlFile.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"");
    return 0;
}
```

and a 64bit-DLL which calls the function

```
 function pfunction = (function)GetProcAddress(hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(0x0001));
 TCHAR m_file[MAX_PATH];
 VARIANT vhtml;
 VariantInit(&vhtml);
 pfunction(m_file, vhtml, path);
```

In 32bit-mode the function call succeeds but in 64bit-mode the function-entry-point is reached but the parameters are invalid? What could I do?

Comment: what exactly does this have to do with `LoadLibraryEx` if its not in your code sample and you say your `GetProcAddress` call succeeds?

Comment: May be related to the fact that x64 does not have __cdecl?

Answer (score 2):

You declared it as a static function but the odds that it is actually an instance method are great.  It works by accident on x86 because the *this* pointer is passed in a register and not on the stack.  You ran out of luck on x64 because it passes the arguments a different way.  Everything is passed in registers, now caller and callee no longer match.  There is otherwise no way for the linker to help you diagnose this issue at build time because you used GetProcAddress.

Declare the method *static*.

Answer (score 0):

In x64 there is no such thing as the `__cdecl` convention, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you'd need to branch correctly for x86-32 and x86-64 builds (also seems you have some compiler specific extensions in there like `:function`). I suspect that the dll you are calling wasn't correctly compiled for x64 (a debugger would give you a more definitive answer).